# How to remove all element from google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have all kind of controls on the map, markers ,infoboxes, infowindows ....

How do i remove them all in order to get a clean map as it was after i created it.

I don't want to re-create the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them as you are creating them inside of an array or collection.

Then reference that array of objects to clear/delete them.

Answer (score 1):

In your function where you initialize the map, just put this option:

```
var mapOptions = {   
   disableDefaultUI: true
}
```

More informations here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI

Comment: I don't want to initialize the map again, just remove all existing elements.